# Default configuration file [ metro-default.xml ] was not found

Tags: java, weblogic

When I am creating a  Jaxws client in my we application at running time one weblogic 12c I am having following error.

I do not know if it is a bug or not?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: MASM0001: Default configuration file [ metro-default.xml ] was not found
```

usng following APIs

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

**weblogic.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<wls:weblogic-web-app
xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.2/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>com.sun.jersey.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>com.sun.research.ws.wadl.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>com.sun.ws.rs.ext.*</wls:package-name>

            <wls:package-name>org.codehaus.jackson.*</wls:package-name>

            <wls:package-name>org.codehaus.jettison.*</wls:package-name>

            <wls:package-name>org.objectweb.asm.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
    <context-root>path</context-root>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I have removed following definition from web.xml file problem is resolved.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
            com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
    </listener-class> </listener> <servlet>
    <servlet-name>wsuser</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> </servlet> <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>wsuser</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/soap/user/wsuser</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping> <session-config>
    <session-timeout>120</session-timeout> </session-config>
```